# in my wordpress automatically logout when i login and refresh dashboard

Tags: wordpress

in live project all things are run properly but when i update all plugin which has update available then after some issues i have faced.

when i login. then its run good and open dashboard 
but after than refresh or open other page user logged out.

how it happen i don't know please help me

i try rename plugin and deactivate them too but not affect.
i try clear filed of all avtive_plugin from option table too at that time it run good 
so i can't understand what is exact problem please explain me and help me to find it.

```
plugins are :- 
Yoast SEO
WPBakery Visual Composer
WP-Optimize
WP Super Cache
WP Rollback
WP Original Media Path
WP Leads Builder For Any CRM Pro
WP Enlight Connect
WP CDN Rewrite
WordPress Post Type Archive Links
WooCommerce Subscriptions
WooCommerce PayPal Checkout Gateway
WooCommerce
Widgets On Pages
Ultimate Addons for Visual Composer
TJ Custom CSS
Smart Slider 3
Rename wp-login.php
Remove Query Strings From Static Resources
Really Simple CAPTCHA
Regenerate Thumbnails
Pricing Tables For Visual Composer - Free
Porto Widgets
Porto Shortcodes
Porto Content Types
Ninja Forms - Zapier
Ninja Forms
Multi Rating
Master Slider Pro
Contact Form 7 Redirection
Contact Form 7
CM On Demand Search And Replace
Captcha
Anti-Malware Security and Brute-Force Firewall
AMP
All In One Schema Rich Snippets
Advanced Custom Fields
A2 Optimized WP
```

Comment: I guess this problem may also from your browser? Check if accept cookies option enabled in settings of browser? If you not sure just try from different browser(which you haven't used yet).

Comment: I tried but still ...